# Does Siesta support HTTP long polling

Tags: swift, siesta-swift

I have an API endpoint which responds with an endless sequence of JSON objects. Like

`GET /commands?since=112233
{"cmd": "mycommand", "params": [...]}
{"cmd": "othercommand", "params": [...]}
...`

The session almost never ends (the server has a setting to time it out eventually, but the typical value is hundreds thousand seconds).

Is there a way to use such an API with Siesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Siesta doesn’t directly support this. A fundamental assumption of Siesta is that URLs are resources that have a (finite) state, and you want to observe changes to that state over time. Siesta thus expects a fully materialized response before it actually starts parsing it & publishes the result. What you’re describing is a different use of HTTP that just doesn’t fit Siesta’s model.

Now if that sequence of JSON objects you’re getting could reasonably be interpreted to represent the *sequence of successive states* of a resource as it changes over time, then it would be possible to make your own networking call outside of Siesta, then use [`Resource.overrideLocalData(…)`](http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Classes/Resource.html#/s:6Siesta8ResourceC17overrideLocalDatayAA6EntityVyypG4with_tF) to publish the updates as they arrive.

Looking at the sample data you gave, however, this looks more like a sequence of *actions* or *events* than a sequence of *states*. Siesta’s resource-centric view of the world might not be a good fit for that. Siesta gives you the most benefit if the question “What is the current state of thing X?” is a meaningful and natural one for your API.

Comment: Thanks! The JSON objects are indeed actions, but these actions are updates to the state(s) stored locally on the client. It's kind of "REST the other way around". So `overrideLocalData(...)` advice may work.